# Azure Portal - Migrate to ARM - Failed during prepare step

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, migrate, azureportal

We are trying to upgrade from ASM to ARM (Virtual Network) via the Azure Portal.

1. Step 1 - validating is working fine.
2. Step 2 - gives an error (See screenshot).

I have no idea in which direction to look for since the error message is not clear to me.
Anyone who can help me out ?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Migrating virtual network which contains virtual machines from ASM(Classic resource) to ARM(Resource manager ) is not supported currently.

You can try moving its resources before migrating , After this once the classic virtual network is migrated ARM virtual network can be peered with classic virtual network  to achieve similar configuration as before.

Please refer the below links for further details:-

. [ASM to ARM not supported configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#unsupported-configurations)  .

.[How to connect v-net from different deployment models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-different-deployment-models-portal) .