# Error migrating Azure Classic storage to ARM

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm using the 'Migrate to ARM' tool in the Azure portal but running into an error as referenced in this post here [Azure Portal - Migrate to ARM - Failed during prepare step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541637/azure-portal-migrate-to-arm-failed-during-prepare-step).

Has anyone run into this error during the prepare step? The validation works, but I get that same error once I begin the 'Prepare' step.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the error message screenshot?
Can you try to migrate Classic Storage account o ARM using PowerShell or CLi and let me know the status?

Sometimes this type of issue may occur when there was VM images, VM machines with disks, or unattached disks in the storage account. Please check to see if this is the case and delete them then retry the migration. The commands to find these resources are in the section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps#step-52-migrate-a-storage-account).

Recommended to refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#step-52-migrate-a-storage-account) and delete if there is any orphan disk object and images that might be impacting the storage account migration.

Have you referred to the suggestion mentioned in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/migration-classic-resource-manager-errors

Step-by-Step: [Migrate your classic Cloud Services to ARM–Storage Migration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/canitpro/step-by-step-migrate-your-classic-cloud-services-to-arm-storage-migration)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The other post I have in my question is the image of the error message I get. I do not currently have any VM images or VM machines in the storage account. Is there a way to check for unattached disks through through the azure portal? As that part I'm not sure of.